# UWP XAML editor doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When I create UWP or windows phone project and try to edit a page in xaml, no visual changes displayed in the editor - it just stays empty. However, borders of selected element are displayed. So it can be defined that editor processes layout right, but displays no visual part of elements.

[image]

The problem occurs on visual studio 2015 proffesional, and also vs 2017 community. So I think problem is not related to IDE, maybe something wrong with SDK.

Hyper-V is enabled if it makes any difference.

Comment: If everything goes wrong, maybe consider a repair installation of your Visual Studio?

Comment: user3079834, I've tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: As a very last resort (I know this because I had issues with Visual Studio as well a couple of times) and if really nothing helps, do a clean uninstall of VC2015 with this https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases (it's an official tool) then restart and do a new install. This sounds like voodoo, but I had once weird issues and that helped me. Maybe it could help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Tashiu,

Set the 
project properties
->Application
->Target version to Windows 10(10.0;Build 10240),

the design view shows up again.

[image]

Comment: Let me know version of Visual Studio by going to help ->about And Windows Version you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Raghu, I'll answer you later, approximately at 8-9 pm CET.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 [Version 10.0.14393].

Tested on:

VS 2015 Professonal (14.0.25431.01 Update 3)

VS 2017 Community (15.0.0+26228.9)

Comment: And also, when I installed Windows SDK (anniversary I think), there was a problem I couldn't create UWP project, so I found solution where I had to manualy fix one visual studio xml configuration file.
If it tells you something.

Comment: And also: I have same VS 2015 version on another computer and the editor DOES work.